# docker-compose run acting differently in other environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I created an image using `docker-compose build`.  I have a docker-compose.yml with two services, `dev` and `distributed`.  The distributed creates an official image.

I then generated a simpler docker compose file, lets name it docker-compose2.yml.  If I do `docker-compose -f docker-compose2.yml run --rm some_service -c "echo $PATH"` in the same computer I generated or executed the `docker-compose build`, I will get the right paths listed.

I then copy the official image using `docker save some_image:0.0.1 > image.tar`, then copy that to another server and do `docker load -i image.tar`.  When I run the same command `docker-compose -f docker-compose.2yml run --rm some_service -c "echo $PATH"`, I wont get the same results as before.  It has some totally new paths.  Also, if I do  `docker-compose -f docker-compose2.yml run --rm some_service -c "echo $PATH; export PATH=/add/some/path:$PATH"; echo $PATH`, the new path added does not seem to be added.  Basically the same list of paths will just be printed twice.

Also, in that server, if I do `docker-compose up` and do `docker exec -it some_container /bin/bash`, once inside, when I type `echo $PATH` I will see the right list of path, not the one I saw from just running docker-compose run.  Any idea whats going on here?

Am I doing anything wrong here?  How do I make it act the same as the original environment?

The original environment does have `docker-compose version 1.26.2, build eefe0d31`, while the server has `docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c`, but didnt think that matters

The docker-compose2.yml just have something very simple like:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  some_service:
    image: some_image:0.0.1
    volumes:
      - .:/some_dir/
      - ~/.aws:/some_dir/.aws:ro
      - ~/boto.cfg:/some_dir/boto.cfg:ro
    environment:
      - AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/some_dir/.aws/config
      - AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/some_dir/.aws/credentials
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    tty: true
```

Comment: `"echo $PATH"` gets expanded by your host system's shell before being passed into `docker exec`.  Does changing this to single quotes `sh -c 'echo $PATH'` make a difference?

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, single quote does fix it.  Sorry, why does single quote work exactly? @DavidMaze